# Reactjs Centralize Components

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way in ReactJS to somehow centralize every component so that when there is a new project I am working on I just need to reference to that centralize component and I will get the latest version of the component. This way all my project will have standard latest components.

-Thanks

Comment: this approach called Shared components. You can check libs like Storybook, DocZ

Comment: Thanks for the fast response ill check it out now.